# Join Value MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

How to get a C02 - 14 - Michael in the ParkingArea table?

> My syntax is failed: SELECT MAX(parkingNumber) FROM parkingArea INSERT
>   INTO parkingArea FROM student WHERE id=14;

Tables are as follow:

Student (Having ID and Name) & Parking(Having ParkingNumber):

```
ID  Name         ParkingNumber
4   Andy         A01
12  Jeo          A02
14  Micheal      C02
```

Desired Insertion in below table 'Parking Area':

```
ParkingNumber ID  Name 
A01           4   Andy         
A02           12  Jeo          
C02           14  Micheal
```

Comment: The syntax should be insert..select

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
INSERT INTO parkingArea
   SELECT (MAX(parkingNumber) FROM parkingArea),id,name  
   FROM student WHERE id=14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO parkingarea 
SELECT (SELECT Max(parkingnumber) 
    FROM   parking 
    WHERE  parkingnumber NOT IN (SELECT parkingnumber 
                                 FROM   parkingarea)), 
    id, 
    name 
FROM   student 
WHERE  id = 14
```

This may not be the best way to do it, so others might have a more optimal solution.

This will ensure there are no overlaps in assigning parking spaces to students, as it will select the maximum value appropriate that isn't already assigned.

Comment: Parkingarea contains 3 columns but only 1 is being supplied so this will fail.

Comment: @P.Salmon - I supply id and Name after my nested SELECT.